# customize insert citation to use \citep{key} in LyX

Tags: lyx, citing, natbib

I am using LyX and would like to know if it is possible to specify which citation command should be used by default for the "Insert -> Citation" function from the menu.

Specifically I am using `natbib` and would like to use `\citep{key}` when using "Insert -> citation"

Comment: It seems to use the previously used citation style, so if you add one citation using the enclosed-in-parenthesis citation style (`\citep`), that is used for the following citations as well (until you use a different one).

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for this at the moment, though there is an open ticket in the bug tracker requesting the feature:

- http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8186

However, in the last comment on that ticket there is a possible workaround, so you could take a look at that.

Also, LyX will remember the last used style, so if you add one reference and change it to the `(<author>, <year>)` style, that will be chosen for any new citations you add, until you change the style of a citation.